# MySQL - does log record the deleted query of a parent-child table?

Tags: mysql, logging, parent-child, record, sqlperformance

In my MySQL db are 2 tables: `Parent` and `Child`. (a field in `Child` refers to the `id` field in `Parent`)

Sometimes I got a record in `Child` deleted.

Does log-enabling (in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) help me observe what actually causes my `Child` record deleted?

One more concern:

In `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, there is this warning:

> ## Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.

How bad could it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
As you mentioned in your question: `a field in Child refers to the id field in Parent`, this means if you delete your `parent`, the associated `child` also gets deleted **if that field is configured as foreign key**.

**Does log-enabling (in /etc/mysql/my.cnf) help me observe what actually causes my Child record deleted?**,

Yes it is possible to log your query. It's up to you however to interpret from logs what query caused the delete.

**How bad could it be?**

It surely decreases the performance, but it totally depends on the amount of data queried and logged and your own server/pc architecture.

There is a nice statistical blog that explains performance degrade:

> Using the general log enabled (general_log = ON) and the log destination is file (log_output = FILE) decreased the throughput by 13.4% and increased the response time by 17.5%.

You can read that blog [here](http://www.fromdual.com/general_query_log_vs_mysql_performance).